# Work related health

Tags: job-change, united-kingdom, health

I am extremely worried about my employment, I have worked for this company for 28+ years, 22 of these years has been as a Warehouse Manager.

In November 2019 I approached my employer and explained that due to my age (62 at this time) that the position was becoming to much for me, and asked for someone to replace me as warehouse manager. It was agreed that a suitable position would be found for me, but nothing was done by my employer so in August 2020 I again contacted my Managing Director and asked to be replaced. An advert was placed but again nothing more was heard. 7th November 2020 we had a catastrophic accident in the warehouse and I suffered extreme stress up to 15 December 2020 when the doctor told me I was under acute stress and that I should take time off. I was off work until 12 January 2021 and returned to work. During the evening of the 12th I was rushed into hospital with a heart attack, the doctors confirmed that I had also suffered another recent heart attack which was possibly on the 15 December 2020. Thankfully I am still here and the company have in fairness looked after me by paying my salary in full.

A colleague has now taken over the role of Warehouse Manager, but I am in limbo as to my role. I have been offered another job driving a VNA truck in the warehouse. Because of my continuing condition and the fact that the warehouse is unheated and cold conditions are detrimental to my health and the job involves shifts after working days for 28 years, I have put this offer on hold until the company can contact my doctor to confirm if I am able to safely work in a cold environment.

My Managing Director has asked "what happens if you are unable to take this role?" I told him that it would be up to him, but he replied "No it will be up to you!" He then explained that this was the only position he could offer and if I refused I would have to leave the company.

I am 64 now and don't want to give up 28 years of working for this company without any reparations. The specialists have confirmed that the heart attack was due to the amount of stress I was under so I hold the company partially if not totally responsible for my current condition. What can I do?

Comment: I'm assuming "MD" here refers to something like "managing director", i.e. your supervisor?  That's a bit confusing in context when you're also talking about a doctor that would be a MD.  What country are you in?  You're asking something that is going to depend heavily on the laws of the country in which you work.

Comment: Yes MD refers to managing Director I am in the UK.

Comment: 1. _Stop_. 2. Do not say anything else to your employer on this. 3. Contact an employment lawyer or Citizen's Advice - your employer is very carefully making the case that you are redundant. How this plays out with your stress/heart attack is something you will need professional advice on.

Comment: **I am 64 now and don't want to give up 28 years of working for this company without any reparations** - What reparations? What does the company owe you? Are you in a financial position that will allow you to retire from this company? If so, I'd suggest doing that.

Answer (score 3):

**Go and talk to a lawyer.**

Citizens Advice Bureau might be a good starting point, but I suspect they will also tell you to visit a lawyer.

Absolutely do not return to work until you have consulted a lawyer. I believe there is a risk that if you return to work in the cold unheated warehouse this might be considered evidence that you voluntarily accept work in these conditions. I might well be wrong, but don't run the risk until a lawyer has told you this is not a problem.

Frankly I'm not sure why you are considering returning to a job here. You yourself write "cold conditions are detrimental to my health", and the new job sounds higher stress than the old one.